# nginx access.log only kept for a day

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, logging, log-files, goaccess

I'm using [goaccess](http://goaccess.prosoftcorp.com/) on Ubuntu Server 12.04 to view my analytics on my web server. I just run the following utility:

```
goaccess -f /var/log/nginx/access.log
```

However I'm only seeing one days worth of data. I was wondering if there are some default setting within nginx to manage this? I've read a little about log file rotation but that really isn't a problem for me at the moment. It appears something is keeping the access.log from showing more than a day.

Can't seem find anything in the nginx documentation to play with some settings.

Comment: Are there any access.log.<number> files? Seems like logrotation

Comment: Your quite right there are, thanks @german_guy is there a way to merge these all together so I can phrase them? They are .gz files?

Answer (score 2):

You can also run it as:

```
zcat -f access.log* | goaccess
```

to avoid creating a new file.

Comment: Full comand for me was `sudo zcat -f /var/log/nginx/access.log* | goaccess --log-format=COMBINED --ignore-crawlers`

Answer (score 0):

The issue was log file rotation as @german_guy pointed out. To get all the output I copied all the access.log* files out and into another directory then un-compressed merged them together using:

```
gunzip access.log*
cat access.log* > new.file
```

Which I then ran with goaccess

```
goaccess -f ~/new.file
```

Now I get all the analytics data.

Answer (score 0):

Another option if you are using Nginx would be to use their free monitoring tool nginx [amplify](https://amplify.nginx.com/docs/guide-introduction.html). This is simple to setup and allows a good deal of customisation by metric and time period and has the advantage that you don't need to keep manually running commands as it's browser based once installed.